# Control the size of subsequent footnote frames - InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, creative-cloud

Is there a way to keep very long footnotes from filling the page? I know you can put in frame breaks manually or setup a paragraph style that limits to one paragraph per page, but neither of those are really viable solutions.

Comment: What would you have the footnote do when it gets longer than your imposed limit? Spill to the next page?

Comment: Exactly, but it should only fill half of that page before spilling over to the next page.

Comment: Can't you create a text box on the master page? The text fills that and you link it to the next one.

Comment: I need an automated solution, that will automatically re-flow as needed and all.

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum the main problem with a master frame for footnotes is that an InDesign footnote has to be in the same frame as the reference. So you can't place the footnote in a master text frame, besides there won't be a footnote on every page...

Comment: Why would the footnote be in the same frame as as the referent? (I assume you mean "This text here* is the referent" is the referent and "* Footnote" is the footnote.) In fact, I would deliberately *never* put them in the same frame. I haven't in 15 years of typesetting.

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum We're on the same page as far as the referent and footnote... But if you're going to use InDesign's built in footnote capability it places the footnote in a virtual frame at the bottom of and within the frame that the referent is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making the footnote and apply a Paragraph Style to it, you can make a Find/replace with a GREP:

- Find a space after the character number xxx `.{300}`
- Replace it for a Page Break `~P`
- Just in the Footnote Paragraph Style

[image: Grep]